# php Foreach loop only shows 1 value instead of all different values

Tags: php, loops, foreach

My foreach loop doesn't loop trough all the results in the database. It only displays the last one, and does that xx times (total number of rows)

My code:

```
$query = db_query('SELECT * FROM push_notifications_messages WHERE msg_appID = :app_id', array(':app_id' => $id));
$qCount = db_query('SELECT * FROM push_notifications_messages WHERE msg_appID = :app_id', array(':app_id' => $id))->rowCount();

$form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(t('Message'), t('Device'), t('Date')),
    'rows' => array(),
    );

foreach($query as $result) {
  for($i = 1; $i <= $qCount; $i++) {
    $form['table']["#rows"]["'r$i'"] = array(
        'c1' => array(
            'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@message', array('@message' => $result->msg_message))),
          ),
        'c2' => array(
            'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@message', array('@message' => $result->msg_device))),
          ),
        'c3' => array(
            'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@message', array('@message' => date("d F Y H:i:s", $result->msg_timestamp)))),
          ),      
      );
  }
}
```

Screenshot of database and result of foreach loop:

[image: db screenshot]

[image: result screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you have a foreach and a for loop to iterate? wouldn't just the foreach alone would be suitable?

Comment: How does $form know how many rows to render then? The part where it now says: "r$i"

Comment: @user3428971 `foreach` will loop through for all of the records.

Answer (score 2):

You are running the `for` loop `$qCount` time for each rows fetched from database. So it is assigning the last `row` to all of the keys. This can be done without the `for` loop. Try with -

```
foreach($query as $key => $result) {
$form['table']["#rows"]["r".$key] = array(
    'c1' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@message', array('@message' => $result->msg_message))),
      ),
    'c2' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@message', array('@message' => $result->msg_device))),
      ),
    'c3' => array(
        'data' => array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => t('@message', array('@message' => date("d F Y H:i:s", $result->msg_timestamp)))),
      ),      
  );
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explenation. It's very clear now :)